# Printing "special" characters with java

Tags: java, string, printing, special-characters

I want to println

```
System.out.println("*_data<*>" text;");
```

as `*_data<*> text;` and also write this to a file. I can't even get it to write to console because of errors...

Answer (score 2):

You have a `"` after <*>. That is causing the error. If you want to print the literal `text` remove the ". If not replace that quote with a + sign and remove the last quote.

Answer (score 1):

simply try:

```
System.out.println("*_data<*>\" text;");
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention the " in the desired output but of course if s/he wants to print the literal quote that is the way to go.